# viewing a canvaspixelarray

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've got a pretty longwinded set of algorithms running on an image source progressively (it's running some computer vision image processes). It would take a while to break them up and visually debug them to a test canvas. Chrome crashes everytime i try to log the canvaspixelarray to the console even though the canvas is only 100x100px,

Can anyone think of a way to view the image effect easily either as data or as result. I remember I saw a way to pop a new browser with the canvas output as an image but i cant find the example again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an initial `canvas` element that hold the processed image, and you are trying to use the `getImageData` to retrieve the current image.

Have you tried using the `toDataUrl` method and just inserting its output to a `src` attribute of an `img` tag?

```
$('img#temp').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL());
```

Answer (score 3):

Igors suggestion reminded me that there was a simple way through this which was simply to pop a new window on each iteration loop of the processing script so i could see where it was going wrong:

```
window.open(canvas.toDataURL() ,"win"+(Math.random()*1000));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the previous answers don't get it right, since what you have is a modified CanvasPixelArray inside an ImageData object, not a canvas.

You can easily import the ImageData to a new canvas. You can do this like ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/invernizzie/vPrHg/)):

```
$(function() {
    // Let's draw something
    var ctx = $('canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100, 50);
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

    // Get some ImageData to work on
    var originalData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);

    // Create another ImageData from its pixel array
    // This will be empty, no image data is copied from the original context
    var outputData = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);
    outputData.width = 100;
    outputData.height = 100;
    for (i = 0; i < originalData.data.length; i++) {
        outputData.data[i] = originalData.data[i];
    }

    // Create a new canvas
    $('body').append('<canvas width=100 height=100 />');
    var outputCanvas = $('canvas').get(1);
    console.log(outputCanvas);

    // Let's now write our data to the new canvas
    outputCanvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(outputData, 0, 0);
});​
```